# How to do a sharedViewModel in iOS like we have in Android?

Tags: ios, swift, architecture

I have been mostly developing Android apps and now diving into iOS app development. The app I am building is for learning purposes and is for ordering coffee. The flow is:

- Screen 1 choose a blend (MainViewController)
- Screen 2 choose a size (SizeViewController)
- Screen 3 choose a flavor (FlavorViewController)
- Screen 4 show total and pay (FinalViewController)

I segue from one screen to next. Based on size and flavor total price is updated and I would like to show the updated total on each screen (except screen 1). On final screen I would like to show size, flavor and of course total. I have a CoffeeModel that I instantiate in sizeViewController. The Model calculates total price like this:

```
mutating func updateTotal() {
    let coffeePrice = getPrice(for: selectedCup)
    let flavorPrice = getFlavorPrice(for : selectedFavor)
    
    total = coffeePrice + flavorPrice
    
    delegate?.updateTotal(to: total)
}
```

the SizeViewController can then get the price through the delegate.

Now the issue is when user hits next and navigate to FlavorViewController how can I use the same CoffeeModal. Do I need to pass this model to next controller in the prepare function?
If I create new one then I will loose the total and it will be a separate instance of coffeeModel.

In Android I could do something like a sharedViewModel. Is there something similar in iOS? Can someone please guide me in the right direction on what sort of architecture should I be following?

funny thing is I am actually drinking coffee while writing this question :)

Comment: Are using uikit or SwiftUI?  The way you manage state and models varies between these two frameworks. Regardless, the basic implementation is a model object that you pass between your views. Rather than a procedural `updateTotal` I would have a computed variable that returns the current price based on the model's properties; size, blend, flavour and so on. The effort of calculating the total isn't particularly great.

Comment: I note that you refer to view controllers, so you are presumably using uikit.   If you are using storyboard scenes then you can simply pass the model in `prepareForSegue`. Delegation probably isn't the best approach here since you have more than one view controller interested in the updated price. UiKit doesn't have built-in binding so it is probably simplest to use procedural code to simply update the price label in each screen as the user makes their selections.

Comment: I am using UIKit. Is there a better way in SwiftUI. BTW I do like SwiftUI just because it's so easy to make UIs in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As Paulw11 suggested I can pass reference to next view controller. But I think instead of using UIKit I am going to use SwiftUI since it offers state management and much more.

Being a Reactjs developer I find SwiftUI is a better solution for the task.

Answer (score 0):

better you use `singleton`:

e.g Creating `singleton` for Total class

```
class Total {
    static let shared =  Total()
    var currentTotal = 0
}
```

and every time I want to update say by 300:

```
func update () {
    Total.shared.currentTotal = Total.shared.currentTotal + 300
}
```

and every time i want to get the total cost:

```
func getTotalCost() -> Int {
    return Total.shared.currentTotal
}
```

Comment: do I have to make flavor, blend and size also singleton since I want to be able to show them on the final screen?

Comment: You can use a singleton, but singletons are generally not encouraged as they can lead to problems with test ability. You can simply pass a reference to your model as you segue between scenes.

Comment: I agree with you on singleton and issues around testability. but going back to your answer what if user navigates back from say screen 3 to 2 to 1. Do I have to then pass the model (reference) back?

Comment: No, because you would be going back to a previous instance. I would, though, use a class, not a struct, for your model so that you get reference rather than value semantics.

Comment: @Paulw11, I like your answer but I cannot accept comment as answer. Also I looked at SwiftUI and state management. I will also try that since that makes so much sense.